# Nginx rewrite - slash at the end

Tags: nginx

I use the proxy_pass directive in the Nginx configuration. I have to add a slash at the end of URLs for catalogs but not for files. Example:

http://localhost/endpoint

should be changed to

http://localhost/endpoint/

but

http://localhost/endpoint.png

should stay the same.

How to achieve this? Rewrite?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why you are doing this? is it because want to fix the URLs for an application you have?

Comment: Because of the server at the end (which I create a proxy for) does redirect (adding slash) if there is no slash at the end, so I have to add slash on my side to avoid the redirect